# z-index takes no effect on an element within angular directive

Tags: html, css, angularjs

code:

```
 directive('ribonUnit', function(){
    return {
      restict: 'A',
      replace: true,
      transclude: false,
      template: '<div class="vPRibbon" name={{score}} style="margin-left:{{offset}}; z-index:100">' +
                 '<div class="vPScore">' +
                    '<span style="font-weight:bold;">{{alphabetic_score}}</span>' +
                 '</div>' +
                 '<div class="vPScoreReasons" data-ng-show="score_hover" style="margin-left:{{reasons_offest}}; z-index:9998"></div>' +
                '</div>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller){
        elem.bind('mouseenter', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.score_hover = true;
          });
        });
```

CSS:

```
vPRibbon {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  cursor: pointer;
  left:11em;
  top:-1em;
  height:7em;
  width:5.3em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/Rating-ribbon.png');
}

.vPScoreReasons{
  background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/score-box.png');
  width: 256px;
  height: 181px;
}
/*.vPScoreBox .vPRibbon {

}*/
.vPContentBox .vPScore span{
  float: left;
  padding: 0em 0.85em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -0.2em;
  font-family: Museo;
}
```

.vPScoreReasons appears under the next .vPScore (the layout is a grid-like view with many products and their scores)

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: This may provide you idea to solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306500/angularjs-slide-divs-up-and-down-with-z-index-changes-isnt-being-respected

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fellow googlenauts, here's a solution: Don't put the angular directive on the target component directly. Instead, wrap it with `<ng-container>` and put the directive on that.

Solution found at http://benprograms.net/2018/06/30/angular-ng-star-inserted/

Answer (score 3):

"Every stacking context has a single HTML element as its root element. When a new stacking context is formed on an element, that stacking context confines all of its child elements to a particular place in the stacking order. That means that if an element is contained in a stacking context at the bottom of the stacking order, there is no way to get it to appear in front of another element in a different stacking context that is higher in the stacking order, even with a z-index of a billion!"
https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 2):

**use !Important**

z-index: 50 !Important;

This will work for you.

Comment: No, actually, it doesn't

Comment: Z-Index will work only when its parent has position : relative, try this too,

Comment: and also check that child must have more z -index then parent so you can use z-index: 9999 !important; which will work for sure

Comment: In this case unfortunately absolute positioning is required

Comment: are you able to provide me fiddle may i able to solve your problem.

Comment: no can do, it is an extension, and those DOM elements are displayed in concatenation with another web page

Comment: A working solution is not always a good solution. I'm facing the same issue. Aren't there any better proposals than adding "important"?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a global variable ZINDEX

And in directive you can use

```
ZINDEX++;
elem[0].style.zIndex = ZINDEX
```

this way, always a new modal will be showing in front